# Proving the solution of generalized confluent hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, hypergeometric-function

According to [wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html), A generalization of the confluent hypergeometric differential equation is given by;

$$y''+\left(\frac{2R}{x}+2F'+p\frac{H'}{H}-H'-\frac{H''}{H'}\right) y'+\left[\left(p\frac{H'}{H}-H'-\frac{H''}{H'}\right)\left(\frac{R}{x}+F'\right)+\frac{R(R-1)}{x^2}+\frac{2R}{x}F'+F''+(F')^2-\frac{q}{H}(H')^2 \right]y=0$$

Which has the solutions $y_1=x^{-R} e^{-F} M(q,p,H)$ and $y_2=x^{-R} e^{-F} O(q,p,H)$, where $M(q,p,H)$  is the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind and $O(q,p,H)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind. Meanwhile, $R,F$ and $H$ are fucntions of $x$.

I tried looking for references about this particular equation online, but i found nothing. I also posted a question in this community:[3872036](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872036/im-looking-for-references-for-generalized-confluent-hypergeometric-differential) to ask for references. Unfortunately, I didn't find any references until now. So I started take this in another way, to prove this equation. I tried proving it but i always get huge expressions and i conclude wrong results. Can any one here help me please with proving the given equation? Thank you guys.

Comment: This is essentially a change of variables. The book on ordinary differential equations from Polyanin and Zaitsev can provide some insight if you look at variants of the confluent hypergeometric equation and how they suggest to get from one to another.